# does any one know is there any jquery plugin for writing text over an image and let the user to place it on any location inside the image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am looking for jquery or js library that can help you place text/shapes over an image.
like in this site http://picfont.com/
it can let you put the text in any location over the image by drag and drop.

Thanks in advance

Comment: pls. google it, you can find tons of plugin for this

Comment: i did search it and not found what I'm looking for but thanks for your answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer depends on whether you want the resulting text to become embedded within the image (i.e. as pixels) such that you could save the whole image (text included) as a file, or whether you're happy for the text to just float above the image.

In the latter case, just use a `<div>` that can be absolutely positioned on top of an `<img>` element.

In the former case the only option I know of is to use an HTML5 `<canvas>` element, and then use `.fillText()` to write text to the canvas:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'),
    ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
    img = new Image;

img.onload = function() {
    canvas.width = this.width;
    canvas.height = this.height;
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0);
    ctx.font = "36pt Verdana";

    ctx.fillStyle = "black";
    ctx.fillText("Test Text", 42, 82);

    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText("Test Text", 40, 80);
};

img.src = ...;
```

See also http://jsfiddle.net/D8ZZS/2/ for a variant of the above where the image is loaded from a `<input type="file">` control using the HTML5 `FileReader` interface.

Comment: Thanks,I need to embedded within the image.do you have any sample for?

Comment: I'm trying to use this snippet to do one with a image path. and do a resize... could you help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

How I said before, the [Google](https://www.google.ro/search?q=text%20on%20image%20jquery%20plugin&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb) is the best friend for anyone who knows to use search engine :)

In this [site](http://www.jquery4u.com/plugins/30-text-captions-overlay-image-plugins/#.UD8bkJZRC48) you'll see 30 jquery plugins which allow you to place text on images.

or use CSS: http://css-tricks.com/text-blocks-over-image/

Comment: Hi,I already found those results.please  look on my link for the sample.Thanks.